# Setting row heights in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using setRowHeights in App Script to change the row heights in a google sheet.  It changes the height but when you go back to the sheet and pick resize row the radio button is still set to "fit to data" not "specify row height", how do I get it to toggle the radio button, I would like it set to "specify row height"

```
function macro() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets()[0].setRowHeights(4,ss.getLastRow(), 24);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which radio button you are talking about?

Comment: if you pick resize row there are 2 choices fit to data and specify row height

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet publicly to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the radio button of "Specify row height" instead of "Fit to data" using Google Apps Script.

  - The situation checked the radio button of "Specify row height" is as follows.

    [image]
  - The situation checked the radio button of "Fit to data" is as follows.

    [image]

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, when Google Spreadsheet service of SpreadsheetApp is used, it seems that the radio button of "Specify row height" cannot be checked. By this, as the default value, the radio button of "Fit to data" is checked even when `setRowHeights` is used. So, in this answer, as a workaround, in order to check the radio button of "Specify row height", I would like to propose to use Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, the radio button of "Specify row height" can be checked like above.

By the way, in your script, in the case of `setRowHeights(4,ss.getLastRow(), 24)`, the row heights of the last row + 3 rows are changed. When you want to change the row heights from 4 row to the last row, please modify it to `setRowHeights(4,ss.getLastRow() - 3, 24)`

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var resource = {
    requests: [{
      updateDimensionProperties: {
        properties: { pixelSize: 24 },
        range: {
          sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), startIndex: 3, endIndex: sheet.getLastRow(),
          dimension: "ROWS"
        },
        fields: "pixelSize"
      }
    }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- When above script is run, the row heights from row 4 to the last row of the 1st tab are changed. And, when the dialog of "Resize row" is opened, you can see that the radio button of "Specify row height" is checked.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

Answer (score 0):

To resize the rows to fit the data with Apps Script you can use the method [autoResizeRows(startRow, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizerowsstartrow,-numrows)

This will automatically detect the needed height for each row and will resize each one individually:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sets the first 15 rows to a height that fits their text.
sheet.autoResizeRows(1, 15);
```